# Using Unity Lenses outside of Unity?

Tags: unity, lenses

Unity lenses are becoming more interesting as time goes on, but unfortunately, you can only have its benefits if using a default Unity session.
While there are alternatives such as kupfer, or the now defunct Unity-2D, a kubuntu** plasmoid to access Unity lenses would be really valuable for integration, or plugins for launchers like kupfer or gnome-do. So since nobody seems interested I'd like to try myself if possible at all.

So my question is: Is there any way to query, and get search results, from Unity lenses without using Unity?
Any dbus-interface, some specific library, anything at all? Doesn't need to be an easy "run this one-line command" solution, or give human-readable results. I can handle C or Python coding.

**(I say Kubuntu but this would be valuable in any other mainline desktop environment, including CLI)

Comment: I don't think so.. Unity Lenses are not in the same "league" as Plasmoids, plasmoids are widgets, lenses are not. Widgets go in the desktop space, lenses are integrated into the Dash, first there would be the need for a Dash in kubuntu to which lenses could be integrated.

Comment: @UriHerrera: Yeah, that's what I want to do.

Comment: There *is* a Dash like plasmoid, Rosa launcher or something like that it's available in Mandriva.

Comment: But, it doesn't interface with Unity, so it doesn't help at all. I want to integrate, not do my own thing.

Comment: Lenses do indeed use D-bus. Try reading this in a mirror: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses Also note the difference between a lense and a scope. I suspect you might want to interface directly to the scopes as they are the bits that return the search results.